# Will corrupted data always show up as corrupted?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, usb, file-corruption

I have the important data from my computer backed up on a USB flash drive. I know I probably should have backed it up to DVDs or something as well, but unfortunately, I did not. My computer was having problems (viruses, malware, errors, etc., even though I am VERY careful about that kind of stuff, running lots of anti-malware programs, inevitably some bad stuff still gets through) so I used Active @KillDisk to zero-fill my hard drive and then reinstall my OS (which is the rather crummy Vista Home Basic, if that matters lol… and my computer is a rather old Toshiba Satellite L300 Series laptop, if THAT matters).

So, now I'm wanting to transfer my important data from the flash drive back to the computer, but to be honest, I'm a little worried. I get lots of lightning storms where I live… some of the strikes have been relatively close to my house, too! I mean, I don't know. I even went to the paranoid degree of storing my USB flash drive inside an old, unplugged microwave to act as a Faraday Cage, just in case (this data is REALLY important to me lol!).

I plan to use Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier to copy the data from the flash drive back to the computer, rather than just dragging-and-dropping it. One thing I like about this program is that it lets you know if any of the data is corrupted, rather than just leaving you guessing. But I guess my concern is, will corrupted data always show up as corrupted on a thing like this? Regardless of *how* it was actually corrupted—lightning strikes, electromagnetic pulse, rogue nanobots, alien ray guns lol—whatever?

I just don't want to be thinking my data's all been transferred safe and sound, when really maybe not all of it has!

Comment: The brief answer is "no", by definition corrupted data could become *anything*, and any method of verification short of comparing with a full copy cannot be guaranteed to detect corruption. That said, common methods (e.g. CRCs, file hashes) will detect the vast majority of common data corruption.

Comment: Thank you, Bob. Is there any particular programs you would recommend in terms of these CRCs, file hashes, etc.?

Comment: This one sounds good—http://corz.org/windows/software/checksum/—but I kind of get the impression that none of these will really help in my situation, since I kinda overwrote the only other copy of this data with 0's. Nothing to compare it to. Again, I see now that this was vastly stupid of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chance of an un-noticed hard drive corruption is very small, but non-zero.   Of-course, just because it copied OK, doesn't mean it will always be OK - media does decay over time.

To check if your data is OK, after copying you may want to run some comparisons between the original and copied data.   There are no doubt lots of ways of doing this (and I live in a Unix world, not a Windows one), but SHA1 and MD5 checksums can tell you with a very high degree of confidence if the source and target data are OK.    (Google "Windows vista checksum" and you should come up with a number of programs which can do this - of-course, you need to run it on both source and target and compare them).

I point out that if the data is really valuable to you, storing copies in off-site locations (and if its not sensitive or too large , additionally on cloud storage in another country if you are worried about things like EMP strikes etc)

Its largely a non-issue, but I don't believe faraday cages can protect significant protection against cosmic radiation - Bits flipping due to Cosmic radiation is not exactly common, but certainly not unheard of - its one of the reasons why servers use ECC memory.

Comment: Hmm… thank you Bob and Davidgo! Not exactly the answer I was hoping for, but I'd rather know the truth than not! Davidgo, since there is no other copy of the original data to compare to, will the methods you describe still work? I agree that I REALLY should have made more than one copy and stored at least one off-site… I was stupid not to! :(

Comment: @JoshZmijewski Unfortunately, there's not much you can do after the fact. You need something to compare *to*. At this point, your last option depends on what format you stored the data in; some formats include their own data checksums. Most forms of storage also include built-in CRC error checking, which will detect major errors (CRC's goal is to be fast, not thorough). Nothing will be 100% (as I mentioned earlier, you need a full copy for that), but you can have some level of assurance.

Comment: @Bob Ok well, some level of assurance is better than nothing; I'll take whatever I can get at this point! So, if the format did have its own data checksum, is there a program I need to make use of that, or will it just do its stuff automatically?

Comment: @JoshZmijewski Depends on the format, really. Some programs will throw an error, others will not notice, others will crash for no apparent reason. Sometimes, it'll only detect metadata corruption, not data corruption (e.g. Word might know if the "end of document" tag is missing, but it won't know if some number `1000` was turned into `4572` in the text). It *really* depends, and you'll have to provide more details for a more specific answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Please tell me what details specifically I should provide, and I will provide them.

Comment: @Bob Also, it seems like this corz.org/windows/software/checksum _DOES_ work without anything to compare it to! Or perhaps I'm not understanding how it works properly?

Comment: @Josh It's just another hashing program, like md5sum. It's useless without known good hashes to compare it to.

Comment: Oh, okay… that makes sense I guess. :( Well so, what details specifically should I provide about the format or whatever?